# Microsoft Dynamics NAV SOAP services not exposed

Tags: dynamics-nav

I'm trying to expose a MS Dynamics NAV Page Web Service through a SOAP interface.  I can configure it just fine through the Web Services admin dialog, but when I check Published it generates the ODATA URL but no SOAP URL.  SOAP's what I want.  What's wrong?  SOAP service is enabled on the NAV server.

Comment: Are you sure you publishing a page, not a Query? Cuz only pages and codeunits results in soap service.

Comment: Thanks, Mak.  It definitely is a page.  If I look at the web services view I see "Page" in the Object Type column.  Just tried to create a Code Unit item and same thing - no SOAP service appears in the table.  I'm stumped!  Any other suggestions?  There are no real options in the process - it's very simple, seemingly - so I can't quite see what I could be doing wrong from a user point of view.

Comment: When you checked `Enable SOAP services` in the instance of Nav server and restart it there should be message in Event Viewer like this `Server instance: InstanceName
'Microsoft Dynamics NAV Business Web Services' is listening to requests at http://ServerAddress:7047/InstanceName/WS/Services.`. This is the address to access web services. Check if this message present in event log and try to navigate in browser (IE preferably) to provided URL.

Comment: Wonder how this one turned out in the end?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure:

1. "Enable SOAP Services" checked
2. "SOAP Base URL" empty
   (in the soap section of NavServer configuration)

And don't forget to restart service!